# using searchlogic with habtm associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, searchlogic

I have the following issue:

I have two classes in my rails app, joined by a HABTM association, like so:

```
#ad.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :specs
#spec.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :ads
```

joined by an ads_specs table.
I'm trying to perform a search on the Ad class using the excellent searchlogic gem. Everything went fine until I wanted to return all the ads that have ALL the selected specs, not any of them.

I tried `@ads = Ad.specs_id_like_all(id1, id2, id3)`but to no results, since I think it's trying to match a spec with an id of "id1, id2, id3". I also tried to .split the ids or directly type them in an array but nothing worked.

My exact search query is:

```
if params[:search]
  @ads = Ad.search(:price_lte => params[:search][:price],
                   :rulaj_lte => params[:search][:rulaj],
                   :fabrication_date_gte => Date.new(params[:search][:"an_fabr(1i)"].to_i,"01".to_i,"01".to_i)).specs_id_like_all(2, 457, 233)

else
  @ads = Ad.all
end
```

Do you guys have any idea how could I solve this problem? I swear it's the last time I use HABTM associations in a rails app, but it's so late to change to a polymorphic one this late in the development process :).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you're trying to perform an SQL IN() query (i.e. `spec_id IN (x,y,z..)` )

Searchlogic does support passing an array to a `*_eq()` method which will use SQL's IN() predicate:

```
Ad.search(:spec_id_eq => [1,2,3,4])
```

**Not sure if this works in older versions of Searchlogic*